# Python - split a list into many lists in a for loop

Tags: python, syntax

Given this input:

```
['1636 19 02 2F', '1637 19 02 2F', '1631 19 02 2F']
```

I'd like to produce this output:

```
['1636']
['19']
['02'] 
['2F']
['1637']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
```

I tried:

```
byte = ['1636 19 02 2F', '1637 19 02 2F', '1631 19 02 2F']

for i in byte:
    d = i.split(' ')
    list_byte = d # ('\n'.join(d))
    print(list(list_byte,))
```

But its output is:

```
['1636', '19', '02', '2F']
['1637', '19', '02', '2F']
```

I have also tried a `nested loop` but then it splits into every character and `join` but that just wrote out the wrong type.

**How can I have the output in separate lists, like this?**

```
['1636']
['19']
['02'] 
['2F']
['1637']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
```

Comment: Why do you want to print it as as *singleton* lists?

Comment: Try `[[i] for i in j.split(' ') for j in byte]`

Comment: Im writing them over to a Access 2016 with this cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO tblMsgBytes (ByteValue) VALUES (?)""",list_byte) and then i has to be in that format, there is a better way... but this is the way i can :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can help.

```
byte = ['1636 19 02 2F', '1637 19 02 2F', '1631 19 02 2F']

for temp in byte :
    for list in temp.split(' '):
        list = [list]
```

Output :

```
['1636']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
['1637']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
['1631']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte = ['1636 19 02 2F', '1637 19 02 2F', '1631 19 02 2F']

for a in byte:
    a_list = a.split(' ')
#     print(a_list)
    for b in a_list:
        print([b])
```

Here you are.

```
['1636']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
['1637']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
['1631']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
for a_string in byte:
    for split_result in a_string.split(' '):
        print [split_result]
```

This gives you a print in the format...

```
['1636']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
['1637']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
['1631']
['19']
['02']
['2F']
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!